# What does template<typename=void> means? Purpose of unnamed template parameters with default value

Tags: c++

I've seen code like this in C++:

```
template<typename=void> 
class A {
//...
```

What is the purpose of this? If it's unnamed, how can making it void possibly helps in anything?

Comment: Someone could write a specialization

Comment: @M.M can't I template my specialization?

Comment: What do you mean by "template my specialization"? I for one am unable to parse this phrase.

Comment: I can add a template when I'm declaring my class specialization. I don't need the base class to be templated

Comment: Huh? Only templates can be specialized

Comment: It is used to enable [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). And [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) should help.